# Making a pivot table from a table with header cells in the first column

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

The source data has the headers in column A and the data in the rest of the columns. Is there anyway to have excel recognize this and make a pivot table?

Comment: Follow this to swap columns with rows https://www.timeatlas.com/switch-excel-columns-rows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It will not recognize it in that format. You must transpose the data for the pivot table to work properly.

1. Have a blank sheet available.
2. Select the cells in the rows that contain the data.
3. Copy the data.
4. When pasting to the new sheet, choose `Transpose` (depending on your
   version it may be in the context menu or in `paste special`).
5. If the data looks correct, delete the original data and replace it
   with the new data set.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-ed1215f5-59af-47e6-953b-0b513b094dc2)